# Login failed for user in Windows Forms app

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I recently downloaded SQL Server Management Studio, logged in as the default user (which is `COMPUTER\USER`), and created a database.

I'm trying to connect to that database in Windows Forms. I have the code

```
conn.ConnectionString =
         "Data Source=COMPUTER\\SQLEXPRESS;" +
         "Initial Catalog=my_database;" +
         "User id=COMPUTER\\USER;" +
         "Password=;";
```

It gives an error "login failed for user". I've tried all sorts of variations but no luck.

Comment: Change it to `Data Source=COMPUTER\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=my_database; Integrated Security=true;`

Comment: Wow, it works! Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

As Siyual pointed out above, I needed an "Integrated Security=true".

Comment: No you did not,. "Integrated Security=true" means you don't get to use User ID and Password in your connection String.